# Is it possible to wrap existing TCP/OpenSSL session with `iostream`?

Tags: c++, boost, iostream

I use custom code to create SSL connection over native Berkeley sockets interface. I need to wrap the resulted socket with `iostream` to use existing algorithms written in C++ with these sockets data.

Is there any easy way to do it without need to implement `stream` and `streambuf` from scratch?

I learned `boost::iostreams` and `boost::asio`.

I didn't find any way to wrap existing OpenSSL session with `boost::asio`.  **Or may be anyone knows how to do that?**

After `boost:asio` I concentrated my research on `boost:iostreams`.

`boost::iostreams` looks like good idea, however, its problem is that it uses read buffering. So, if we need to read just 1 byte from SSL session, it asks the TCP device to read 4 kilobytes and results in timeout. From the other hand, when I set buffer size to `0`, `boost::iostreams` start to call `write` method for each byte, so when I try to write 10 bytes to stream, it calls `SSL_write` 10 times. TCP device itself can not use write buffering, because there are no way to forward `flush` method to device, so application level protocol may expect that data is sent to another peer while the data remains in output buffer.

**So, we need unbuffered read and buffered flushable write; is that possible with `boost::iostreams`?**

Comment: No, you have to implement a subclass of `rdbuf`, from scratch, as you expected. There are very few parts of C++ that offer instant gratification. More often than not you will have to do all the work yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution myself.

First of all, it is required to mark the device as flushable. Because there are not ready-made template for such device, you have to inherit `device<dual_use, Ch>` and override its category with multiple inheritance:

```
struct category : device<dual_use, Ch>::category, flushable_tag
```

Now when you will call `flush` on stream, it will forward the call to your device.

Next step is to disable stream own buffering (i. e. call `open` with 2nd and 3rd parameters equal to `0`).

In such configuration `boost` will write to device each byte of data separatelly. However, you can implement buffering on device level, and flush the buffer on `flush` call.